# Finding $\binom n0+\binom n3+\binom n6+\cdots $

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

How to get
$$\binom n0 + \binom n3 + \binom n6 + \cdots$$

MY ATTEMPT

$$(1+\omega)^n = \binom n0 + \binom n1 \omega^1 + \binom n2 \omega^2 + \cdots$$

$$(1+\omega^2)^n = \binom n0 + \binom n1 \omega^2 + \binom n2 \omega^4 + \cdots $$

$$(1 + 1)^n = 2^n = \binom n0 + \binom n1 + \binom n2 + \cdots$$

$$(1+\omega)^n + (1+\omega^2)^n + (1 + 1)^n = 3 \left(\binom n0 + \binom n3 + \binom n6 + \cdots\right)$$

But how to solve LHS? I got the required equation in RHS

Comment: Your question isnt clear.

Comment: Two answer appear below, neither of them mine, and yet I'm the only person who's up-voted the question.

Comment: $\ldots\,$ and now three answers appear including mine and I'm still the only person who's up-voted the question. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

You have
$$(1+\omega)^n+(1+\omega^2)^n+2^n=3\left(\binom n0+\binom n3+\binom n6+\cdots\right)$$

Now note that
$$(1+\omega)^n+(1+\omega^2)^n=(-\omega^2)^n+(-\omega)^n=(-1)^n(\omega^n+\omega^{2n})$$

This is equal to $(-1)^n\cdot 2$ if $n\equiv 0\pmod 3$ or $(-1)^n\cdot (-1)=(-1)^{n+1}$ if $n\not\equiv 0\pmod 3.$

Comment: I don't get the last line.  LHS should just be (-1)^n(\omega^n+\omega^{2n}) right? I don't know what mod is. I think till here it is okay for me .

Comment: @AliHasan: $n\equiv 0\pmod 3$ means that $n$ is divisible by $3$. So, if $n$ is divisible by $3$, we have $\omega^n+\omega^{2n}=1+1=2$ because we have $\omega^3=1$. If $n$ is not divisible by $3$ (this is equivalent to $n\not\equiv 0\pmod 3$), then we have $\omega^n+\omega^{2n}=\omega+\omega^2=-1$ (why?)

Answer (score 1):

$$(1+\omega)^n+(1+\omega^2)^n+2^n\\
=(-\omega^2)^n+(-\omega)^n+2^n\\
=(-1)^n(\omega^{2n}+\omega^n)+2^n\\
$$
i) $n=3m$:
$$(-1)^n(\omega^{2n}+\omega^n)+2^n=2\cdot(-1)^n+2^n$$
ii) $n=3m+1$ or $3m+2$:
$$(-1)^n(\omega^{2n}+\omega^n)+2^n=(-1)^{n+1}+2^n$$

Comment: The last equality does not always hold. Take $n=3$.

Comment: @Kay K. what about LHD when $r=n$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\omega = \dfrac{-1+ i\sqrt 3} 2 = \cos120^\circ + i\sin120^\circ$.

Then $\omega^3 = 1$, and $1+\omega = \cos60^\circ + i\sin60^\circ$, so  $(1+\omega)^2 = \omega$.

A bit of arithmetic shows that $n\mapsto(1+\omega)^n + (1+\omega^2)^n$ is a **periodic function** with period $6$:
\begin{array}{c|c}
n & (1+\omega)^n + (1+\omega^2)^n \\
\hline
0 & \phantom{+}2 \\
1 & \phantom{+}1 \\
2 & -1 \\
3 & -2 \\
4 & -1 \\
5 & \phantom{+}1
\end{array}
Therefore
$$
\binom n 0 + \binom n 3 + \binom n 6 + \cdots = \frac{2^n + \text{a periodic term never exceeding $2$ in absolute value} } 3.
$$