# Factoring out a coefficient from binomial

Tags: binomial-coefficients, factorial, factoring, binomial-theorem

I watched a youtube video (I cannot find it anymore) however, the author showed that the following binomial equation could be factored (If I remembered it correctly.)

$$\binom{n}{n+2k}=\binom{n}{n+k}\frac{1+(-1)^k}{2}$$

I cannot see how this was derived, for example I have tried the following:

$$\frac{n!}{(n+2k)!(n-(n+2k))!}$$

But cannot see how the above works.

Comment: Probably you didn't remember the formula. If $k>0$, both ${n \choose {n+2k}}$ and ${n \choose n+k}$ are zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probably saw was
$$\sum_{k\ge 0} a_{2k} = \sum_{k\ge 0} a_k \frac{1+(-1)^k}{2},$$ which holds because
$$\frac{1+(-1)^k}{2}=
\begin{cases} 1&\text{if $2\mid k$},\\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Ok I see, essentially I got the k belongs to the integers, therefore we only want to iterate over the positive integers, am I correct? Therefore, for k even we get 1 and for k odd we get 0. However, If I get something like $\binom{n}{n+pk}$ with p denoting any natural number, would this become something like $\binom{n}{n+k} \cdot \frac{(p-1)+(-1)^k}{p}$?

Comment: No, for general $p$, you use $p$th roots of unity.  See [summation] [roots-of-unity]

Comment: For an example with $\sum_k \binom{n}{3k+1}$, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3644225/what-is-the-value-of-binomn1-binomn4-binomn7-binomn10-bi/3644277#3644277